# UiButton Position not change programmatically ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am doing autosizing tableview like tableview height will change according to its content. For that I am using this code

```
  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.tblReceipt.sizeToFit()
    var frame = self.tblReceipt.frame
    frame.size.height = self.tblReceipt.contentSize.height
    self.tblReceipt.frame = frame 
}
```

and I am able to do this functionality.

than I am adding button bottom to tableview.
to set top position from tableview I am using this code

```
let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.btnPrint, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: self.tblReceipt, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)

        self.btnPrint.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([pinTop])
```

I am doing this because whatever size of tableview is there.button should be always top from tableview.

But this is not working. Here are screenshots of error

[image]

[image]

UITableView Delegate Method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrReceipt.count
  }
```

Data Source method

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell:PrintCell = (tblReceipt.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PrintCell"))! as! PrintCell
        cell.lblProductName.text  = arrReceipt[indexPath.row].objectForKey("product_name") as? String
        cell.lblProductPrice.text = String(format:"%.2f", arrReceipt[indexPath.row]["product_price"]!!.doubleValue)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Yes exactly.i want this

Comment: @pedrouan Please check my updated question.i add image what i want in my app.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel table height will not change when new cell added, so your button staying at the same position. Table height remains same and additional rows will be added as you increase the row count.

Comment: @raki Yes that's my point.any solution?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel look at Umair Afzal's answer in this thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your button in the last cell of `UITableView` for that you can create a custom Cell like below.

Goto File->New->Cocoa Touch Class then name yourCell and create Xib

[image]

Now click on newaly created Xib and design your cell. In your case you can put a button in the cell and apply some autoLayout Constraints as follows

[image]

Now create an IBOutlet of your button in your custom cell class. you custom cell class Should look something like this.

```
import UIKit

class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


class func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> YourTableViewCell {

    let kYourTableViewCellIdentifier = "kYourTableViewCellIdentifier"
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "YourTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: kYourTableViewCellIdentifier)
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kYourTableViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
    
    return cell
}

}
```

Your custom cell is ready to use now. So in your tableViewController class `cellForRowAtIndexPath` writhe this code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if (indexPath.row == (arrReceipt.count)) {
    
    let cell = YourTableViewCell.cellForTableView(tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    // code for last cell 
    return cell

} else {
    let cell:PrintCell = (tblReceipt.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ButtonCell"))! as! PrintCell

    // code for other rows in tableView
    return cell
   }    
}
```

and in `numberOfRowsInSection` return yourDataSourceArray.count + 1

I Hope this will help. If you find any difficulty let me know.

Comment: warning at return UITableViewCell() will never executed

Comment: opps, Sorry remove that line

Comment: @UmairAfzal i tried your code.but i can not see button in tableview

Comment: @pedrouan Thanks brother for your efforts and kindness

Comment: @KrutarthPatel what issue are you facing ? debug and tell me some specific   issue.

Comment: @UmairAfzal i did not face any issue.but button is not displaying in tableview

Comment: put a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check weather the code for button is being executed or not.

Comment: @UmairAfzal i add this code.cell.btnPrint.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().gives fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: what is nil exactly ? cell or btn ?

Comment: first i was getting cell nil.so i add this code. tblReceipt.registerClass(ReceiptCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReceiptCell")

Comment: but right now when debug come at  cell.btnPrint.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor(). i got error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: are you using same code which i gave you ? did you put "cellForTableView" method in your custom cell class as I suggested ?

Comment: when  i add    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().this is working

Comment: Okay Noe give specific answers to my questions. Did you put break point in cell for row at indexPath and checked that the button cell code is being executed ?

Comment: Button row means other data right? yes it is calling

Comment: you Can customize your cell in "awakeFromNib" method of custom cell's class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123947/discussion-between-umair-afzal-and-krutarth-patel).

Comment: i am unable to tap on button in tableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider creating a whole UIView in code and then place the button where you needed. Example: FooterView?

I found this code for you:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAddRowTapped:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
aButton.frame = frame;
[footerView addSubView:aButton];
[yourTableNmae setTableFooterView:footerView];
```